# Java - TreeMap User Input

Tags: java

I am creating a bank system project.

I am having trouble incorporating the user input/scanner with treemap.

I want to create a account with account number, account name with account number being the key.

When the account has been stored, I will create a linked list for transactions which will only store the last 6 transaction.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to add account to a tree map from user input from
 the command box?

Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Bank {
  TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > accounts = new TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > ();



  public int openNewAccount(int accountNumber, String holderName, double openingBalance, String holderAddress, String openDate) {

    }
    //End of Class
}
```

```
import java.util.*;
public class BankAccount {
  private int accountNumber;
  private String holderName;
  private String holderAddress;
  private String openDate;
  private double currentBalance;

  private List < Transaction > latestTransactions = new ArrayList < Transaction > ();

  public BankAccount(int accountNum, String holderNam, String holderAdd,
    String openDat) {
    accountNumber = accountNum;
    holderName = holderNam;
    holderAddress = holderAdd;
    openDate = openDat;
  }

  public String getAccountInfo() {
    return "\nAccount number: " + accountNumber + "\nHolder's name: " + holderName + "\nHolder's address: " + holderAddress + "\nOpen Date: " + openDate + "\nCurrent balance: " + currentBalance;
  }

  public int getAccountNum() {
      return accountNumber;
    }
    //End Of Class  

}
```

```
import java.util.*;
public class Transaction {
  private List < Transaction > transactions = new ArrayList < Transaction > ();

  public Transaction(int accountNumber, double currentBalance) {

  }

  public void addTransaction(Transaction t) {
    if (transactions.size() + 1 > 6)
      transactions.remove(0); // deletes the list element on the first place

    transactions.add(t);
  }

  public void deposit(double currentBalance, double amount) {

    if (amount <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
    } else {
      currentBalance = currentBalance + amount;
    }
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount, double currentBalance) {
      if (amount <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
      } else {
        if (currentBalance < amount) {
          System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
        } else {
          currentBalance = currentBalance - amount;
        }
      }
    }
    //End of Class
}
```

Comment: Dude.. You've gotto show us atleast some code.

Comment: Google for Scanner and treemap. You'll get lot of tutorials.

Comment: How are you even creating the `BankAccount`?  You don't instantiate one anywhere.

Comment: @Makoto what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is, you've got a lot of structure and definition here, but I don't see your objects interacting with one another.  You don't new up a `BankAccount`.  It could be that this is where you're stuck, so let me rephrase:  what would you realistically expect to get back from the `openNewAccount` method in your `Bank` class?

Comment: By having openNewAccount in the bank class, I was expecting it to add it to the tree map.

Comment: @Michael what is the use of your addTransaction?

Comment: @Michael im currently working on this hope you will like my answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you to understand what to do.

**Note :** I provide some comments inside so that you can understand. please comment if there still unclear about this.

**Bank Class**

Provide Setter & Getter to your Pojo(Plain Old Java Object).

```
public class Bank {

    private int bankId;
    private String bankName;
    private TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> bankAccounts = new TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount>();

    public Bank(){}

    public Bank(int bankId,String bankName){
        this.bankId = bankId;
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }

    public int getBankId() {
        return bankId;
    }
    public void setBankId(int bankId) {
        this.bankId = bankId;
    }
    public String getBankName() {
        return bankName;
    }
    public void setBankName(String bankName) {
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }
    public TreeMap<Integer, BankAccount> getAccounts() {
        return bankAccounts;
    }
    public void setAccounts(TreeMap<Integer, BankAccount> accounts) {
        this.bankAccounts = accounts;
    }
}
```

**BankAccount Class**

```
public class BankAccount {

    private int accountId;
    private String holderName;
    private String holderAddress;
    private String openDate;
    private double currentBalance;

    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

    //Provide Blank Constructor
    public BankAccount(){}

    //Constructor with an arguments.
    public BankAccount(int accountNum, String holderNam,double currentBalance, String holderAdd,String openDate) {
            this.accountId = accountNum;
            this.holderName = holderNam;
            this.holderAddress = holderAdd;
            this.openDate = openDate;
            this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

    // Always Provide Setter and Getters
    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }
    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }
    public String getHolderName() {
        return holderName;
    }
    public void setHolderName(String holderName) {
        this.holderName = holderName;
    }
    public String getHolderAddress() {
        return holderAddress;
    }
    public void setHolderAddress(String holderAddress) {
        this.holderAddress = holderAddress;
    }
    public String getOpenDate() {
        return openDate;
    }
    public void setOpenDate(String openDate) {
        this.openDate = openDate;
    }
    public double getCurrentBalance() {
        return currentBalance;
    }
    public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance) {
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "\nAccount number: " + accountId + "\nHolder's name: " + holderName + "\nHolder's address: " + holderAddress + "\nOpen Date: " + openDate + "\nCurrent balance: " + currentBalance;
    }

}
```

**Transaction Class**

```
public class Transaction {

    private int transactionId;
    private String transactionType;
    private double transactionAmount;
    private double moneyBeforeTransaction;
    private double moneyAfterTransaction;

    public Transaction(){}

    public Transaction(int transactionId,String transactionType,double transactionAmount, double moneyBeforeTransaction){
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
        this.moneyBeforeTransaction = moneyBeforeTransaction;
    }

    public int getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(int transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    public String getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }

    public double getTransactionAmount() {
        return transactionAmount;
    }

    public void setTransactionAmount(double transactionAmount) {
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    }

    public double getMoneyBeforeTransaction() {
        return moneyBeforeTransaction;
    }

    public void setMoneyBeforeTransaction(double moneyBeforeTransaction) {
        this.moneyBeforeTransaction = moneyBeforeTransaction;
    }

    public double getMoneyAfterTransaction() {
        return moneyAfterTransaction;
    }

    public void setMoneyAfterTransaction(double moneyAfterTransaction) {
        this.moneyAfterTransaction = moneyAfterTransaction;
    }

    //Override the toString() method of String ? 
    public String toString(){
        return "Transaction ID : " + this.transactionId +
                " Transaction Type : " + this.transactionType +
                " Transaction Amount : " + this.transactionAmount +
                " Money Before Transaction : " + this.moneyBeforeTransaction + 
                " Money After Transaction : " + this.moneyAfterTransaction;
    }

}
```

Always Separate Your Transaction Process or any other process inside of your POJO

see this.

**TransactionProcess Class**

```
public class TransactionProcess {

    //Always Provide another class for process.
    //Pass the bankAccount of the user
    public void deposit(BankAccount bankAccount, double depositAmount) {
        //Get the CurrentBalance
        double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();

        //First Argument : set the Id of transaction
        //Second Argument : set the Type of Transaction
        //Third Argument : set the TransactionAmount 
        //Fourth Argument : set the Balance Before the transaction (for record purposes)
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(),"Deposit",depositAmount,currentBalance);

        if (depositAmount <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
        } else {
            //Set the updated or transacted balance of bankAccount.
            bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance + depositAmount);
            //then set the MoneyAfterTransaction
            transaction.setMoneyAfterTransaction(bankAccount.getCurrentBalance());
            //after the transaction add it to the list of Transaction of bankAccount
            bankAccount.getTransactions().add(transaction);
        }

    }

    // Explanation same as above
    public void withdraw(BankAccount bankAccount,double withdrawAmount) {
        double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(),"Withdraw",withdrawAmount,currentBalance);

        if (withdrawAmount <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
        } else {
            if (currentBalance < withdrawAmount) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
            } else {
                bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance - withdrawAmount);
                transaction.setMoneyAfterTransaction(bankAccount.getCurrentBalance());
                bankAccount.getTransactions().add(transaction);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**BankProcess Class**

```
public class BankProcess {

    // return the  Updated list of BankAccounts
    public TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> openNewAccount(TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> bankAccounts,BankAccount bankAccount) {
        //Get the List of existing bank Accounts the add the new BankAccount to it.
        bankAccounts.put(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);
        return bankAccounts;
    }

}
```

And Lastly for the Main Class
This will Accept only one Bank Account create your own process to accept alot of BankAccount.
I already give the Idea. I hope you understand it.

```
Public class MainSample {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        BankProcess bankProcess = new BankProcess();
        TransactionProcess transactionProcess = new TransactionProcess();

        //Adding new Bank & Bank Account

        // We Already Declare the information about The Back.
        Bank bank = new Bank(1,"GTS");
        BankAccount bankAccount = null;


        //accepting bankAccount informations.

        System.out.print("Account Id: ");
        int accountId = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Holder Name: ");
        String holderName = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Opening Balance: ");
        Double openingBalance = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Holder Address: ");
        String holderAddress = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Open Date: ");
        String openDate = scan.next();

        //Set the information gathered to BankAccount.
        bankAccount = new BankAccount(accountId,holderName,openingBalance,holderAddress,openDate);

        //Call the Method of BankProcess openNewAccount
        //then set the New|Lastest list of bankaccounts
        bank.setAccounts(bankProcess.openNewAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));


        //Here is sample Transaction
        //Deposit.
        System.out.println("Enter Deposit Amount");
        Double depositAmount = scan.nextDouble();

        //This will Process the Transaction of user
        transactionProcess.deposit(bankAccount, depositAmount);

        //Withdraw
        System.out.println("Enter Withdraw Amount");
        Double withdrawAmount = scan.nextDouble();

        transactionProcess.withdraw(bankAccount, withdrawAmount);

        //END


        //this will be Executed After you successfully finished all process 
        //this will provide the list of bankAccount in a certain bank.
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, BankAccount> bankAccounts : bank.getAccounts().entrySet()){
            //Use the toString method of BankAccount, this will Provide all the information of user
            System.out.println(bankAccounts.getValue().toString());
        }

        //This will output the List of the Transactions done by the Current BankAccount(User)
        for(Transaction transaction : bankAccount.getTransactions()){
            System.out.println(transaction.toString());
        }


    }

}
```

Output Is :

```
Bank Id: 1
Bank Name: SampleBank
Account Id: 1
Holder Name: SampleName
Opening Balance: 10000
Holder Address: SampleAddress
Open Date: SampleDate
Enter Deposit Amount
1000
Enter Withdraw Amount
2000

Account number: 1
Holder's name: SampleName
Holder's address: SampleAddress
Open Date: SampleDate
Current balance: 9000.0
Transaction ID : 0 Transaction Type : Deposit Transaction Amount : 1000.0 Money Before Transaction : 10000.0 Money After Transaction : 11000.0
Transaction ID : 1 Transaction Type : Withdraw Transaction Amount : 2000.0 Money Before Transaction : 11000.0 Money After Transaction : 9000.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Question. If I only want one bank account, how would I proceed? E.g. When the program runs, it already starts in a bank and all the user does is interact with that one bank by adding account etc.... What can be done to the Bank class?

Comment: ahmm you mean you want to get specific bankAccount ? if yes just call the `bank.getBankAccounts().get(accountId);`

Comment: I only want the user to interact with the bank account, not to create a new bank with id and name. There should create a bank account which should be saved into a bank already provided in the code.

Comment: aaaa. you want to have an existing bank ?

Comment: take a look on my update :) btw. since when you start in this language?

Comment: I started learning on 25th August and mainly been using BlueJ and basic data structure e.g. Arraylist only. I have only moved to NetBean at the start of November and been really struggling. Thanks for the help. Ill comment under the answer if I need help.

Comment: okey just comment here :) and i will use what i learned for these past 4 months to help you :))

Comment: I have been following the advice you have given me but came across a problem. For console menu, I need it to be more in depth e.g. 1. Create account. And within that is where you input account id, account name etc. I been told I should use switch, do, while.

Comment: @michael ask it as a new question and post your codes and errors so that we can answer it well. :)) then give me the link of your new question.